# Flutter display Object entries

Tags: flutter, dart, object, future

So I'm new to flutter and I simply want to display an Object that I receive from a server.

The Object looks something like this. So normally i would do something like Global.mEnergy.value

```
{
   "Global":{
      "mEnergy":{
         "value":"-0",
         "name":"WZ Wärmemenge",
         "id":730,
         "unit":"kWh",
         "type":"value"
      },
      "mPower":{
         "value":"-0.0",
         "name":"WZ Leistung",
         "id":732,
         "unit":"kW",
         "type":"value"
      },
      "xRelease":{
         "value":"34",
         "name":"Releaseinfo",
         "id":727,
         "unit":"",
         "type":"value"
      },
      "xVersion":{
         "value":"12.00",
         "name":"Version Software",
         "id":711,
         "unit":"",
         "type":"value"
      },
      "name":"Test"
   },
   "HW1":{
      "rState_HW1":{
         "value":"10",
         "name":"State",
         "id":222,
         "unit":"",
         "type":"value"
      },
      "pSetTemp_HW1":{
         ...
      },
      "rTopTemp_HW1":{
         ...
      },
      "pMinTemp_HW1":{
         ...
      },
      "pHWChrgTime1Begin_HW1":{
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

But I have really no idea how to start. I know i have to create a class like that

```
class Device {
  final Object hw1;
  final Object hw2;
  final Object circuit1;
  final Object circuit2;
  final Object circuit3;
  final Object circuit4;
  final Object global;

  const Device(
      {required this.hw1,
      required this.hw2,
      required this.circuit1,
      required this.circuit2,
      required this.circuit3,
      required this.circuit4,
      required this.global});

  factory Device.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Device(
      hw1: json['HW1'] as Object,
      hw2: json['HW2'] as Object,
      circuit1: json['1'] as Object,
      circuit2: json['2'] as Object,
      circuit3: json['3'] as Object,
      circuit4: json['4'] as Object,
      global: json['Global'] as Object,
    );
  }
}
```

Is there no easy way how I can access the object like this?

```
 Text(snapshot.data!.global.mEnergy.value)
```

Comment: Ok, after changing "Object" to "Map", i can easily access the value. But is this the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

Most often, my strategy is to create classes that mimic the data structure for an API. That gives me the type-safe approach to getting and manipulating the data I need to.

Taking your data set, I have come up with some classes. The first is `CommonProperties`. Objects such as "mEnergy" in "global" and "rState_HW1" in "HW1" are composed of these properties.

```
class CommonProperties {
  double? value;
  String? name;
  int? id;
  String? unit;
  String? type;
  CommonProperties({
    this.value,
    this.name,
    this.id,
    this.unit,
    this.type
  });
  factory CommonProperties.fromJson(dynamic data) {
    data = data ?? {};
    return CommonProperties(
      value: data["value"],
      name: data["name"],
      id: data["id"],
      unit: data["unit"],
      type: data["type"]
    );
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      "value": value,
      "name": name,
      "id": id,
      "unit": unit,
      "type": type
    };
  }
}
```

Now you have the 2 upper-tier objects called "Global" and "HW1". These are composed of `CommonProperties` objects.

```
class Global {
  CommonProperties? mEnergy;
  CommonProperties? mPower;
  CommonProperties? xRelease;
  CommonProperties? xVersion;
  String? name;
  Global({
    this.mEnergy,
    this.mPower,
    this.xRelease,
    this.xVersion,
    this.name
  });
  factory Global.fromJson(dynamic data) {
    data = data ?? {};
    return Global(
      mEnergy: CommonProperties.fromJson(data["mEnergy"]),
      mPower: CommonProperties.fromJson(data["mPower"]),
      xRelease: CommonProperties.fromJson(data["xRelease"]),
      xVersion: CommonProperties.fromJson(data["xVersion"]),
      name: data["name"]
    );
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      "mEnergy": mEnergy!.toJson(),
      "mPower": mPower!.toJson(),
      "xRelease": xRelease!.toJson(),
      "xVersion": xVersion!.toJson(),
      "name": name
    };
  }
}

class HW1 {
  CommonProperties? rState_HW1;
  CommonProperties? pSetTemp_HW1;
  CommonProperties? pTopTemp_HW1;
  CommonProperties? rTopTemp_HW1;
  CommonProperties? pMinTemp_HW1;
  CommonProperties? pHWChrgTime1Begin_HW1;
  HW1({
    this.rState_HW1,
    this.pSetTemp_HW1,
    this.pTopTemp_HW1,
    this.rTopTemp_HW1,
    this.pMinTemp_HW1,
    this.pHWChrgTime1Begin_HW1,
  });
  factory HW1.fromJson(dynamic data) {
    data = data ?? {};
    return HW1(
      rState_HW1: CommonProperties.fromJson(data["rState_HW1"]),
      pSetTemp_HW1: CommonProperties.fromJson(data["pSetTemp_HW1"]),
      pTopTemp_HW1: CommonProperties.fromJson(data["pTopTemp_HW1"]),
      rTopTemp_HW1: CommonProperties.fromJson(data["rTopTemp_HW1"]),
      pMinTemp_HW1: CommonProperties.fromJson(data["pMinTemp_HW1"]),
      pHWChrgTime1Begin_HW1: CommonProperties.fromJson(data["pHWChrgTime1Begin_HW1"]),
    );
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      "rState_HW1": rState_HW1!.toJson(),
      "pSetTemp_HW1": pSetTemp_HW1!.toJson(),
      "pTopTemp_HW1": pTopTemp_HW1!.toJson(),
      "rTopTemp_HW1": rTopTemp_HW1!.toJson(),
      "pMinTemp_HW1": pMinTemp_HW1!.toJson(),
      "pHWChrgTime1Begin_HW1": pHWChrgTime1Begin_HW1!.toJson(),
    };
  }
}
```

Finally, I put it all together to build a class that represents the entire `DataSet`.

```
class DataSet {
  Global? global;
  HW1? hw1;
  DataSet({
    this.global,
    this.hw1
  });
  factory DataSet.fromJson(dynamic data) {
    data = data ?? {};
    return DataSet(
      global: Global.fromJson(data["global"]),
      hw1: HW1.fromJson(data["HW1"])
    );
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      "global": global!.toJson(),
      "hw1": hw1!.toJson(), 
    };
  }
}
```

Notice that each class has a constructor for `fromJson(data)` and a method for `toJson()`. This is helpful to easily go to and from JSON data for interacting with APIs and such.

Now that I have everthing put together, I can pass the parsed JSON object from an API call into the `DataSet.fromJson(data)` constructor and I will have a type-safe object to work with all the data within that data set.

```
var parsedData = json.decode(httpResponse.body);
DataSet dataSet = DataSet.fromJson(parsedData);

print(dataSet.global.mEnergy.value);
print(dataSet.hw1.rState_HW1.value);
```

Comment: I was hoping to get away with a little less "complex" approach, but there does not seem to be any. Anyway, thanks for that i will give it a try.

Comment: If you don't want to use the classes, you could just get the data from the `parsedData` like this => `parsedData["Global"]["mEnergy"]["value"]`. Would you prefer that approach?

Comment: My understanding is that i have to use a class because of Future. 

But i will go with your first approach. It is just a lot to do(and seems unnecessary complex, but i guess thats how dart works) for someone that is new to flutter.